# Employee Performance Improvement Plan Format

Tags: manager, performance-reviews, employees

I am working as a Manager in a QA based firm. I need to prepare a 15 days EPIP. But I have not done this before and don't know what to put in it. Certainly this employee has issues, with his Attitude, Performance, Rant, management is not happy with him.

So looking for a format which has 15 days plan, more attributes apart from these two.

Checked this https://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions/comments/3d66th/iama_software_engineer_on_a_pip_performance/ but couldn't help in planning for 15 days.

Comment: Why not just get it over with and fire them outright? A PIP is really a sign to the employee that they're going to be fired. Maybe in 15 days, maybe 6 weeks, maybe in a year, but eventually that PIP will be used to justify their termination.

Comment: "I need to prepare a 15 days EPIP."  Who told you you need to do this?  I suggest asking them what they want.

Comment: For clarification is the goal of the PIP a precursor to firing or an attempt at improvement?  I mean if the employee turned their attitude and performance around would management be okay keeping him on or has that boat already sailed.

Comment: @Myles PIPs are almost always a precursor to a firing.  I have yet to meet anyone who has survived one.

Comment: @RichardU They do exist.  We have had people on this SE who have claimed to have made it through one and there definitely are stories out there.  Unfortunately without knowing the goal of the PIP it's difficult to answer the question.  If it's for legitimate improvement your approach would be radically different from if it were a firing precursor.

Comment: @Myles I'm sure you'll find people.  It has been my experience that PIPs are usually just the final nail in the coffin.  a 15 day PIP is almost certainly for the purpose of gathering data for a firing.

Comment: @RichardU - Agreed.  90 days would be a MINIMUM viable PIP, including progress meetings and review.  This is a 'tactic' to either fight unemployment compensation (and the resultant premium increase) or anticipated civil action.  HR needs to be straight with paul about what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

For format, check with your HR, they will most likely have a company specific format.

What I think you are really having trouble with is how to compress this to 15 days instead of a longer period. I would suggest that you include a followup meeting at least weekly to go over the progress on the plan. Depending on what you write, you might want a daily meeting or one every couple of days.  What you need to do is be very specific about what actions the person needs to take or no longer do.

Discuss with your manager what they want to put into it. If the employee has multiple problems, prioritize fixing them, a person can legitimately only work on so much.

Since the timeline is so compressed, I have the sense that this is really a way to check off all the blocks to fire someone for cause (to the skeptics, yes I have seen PIPs that were used to salvage otherwise good employees not just to justify firing them).

In this case, it is important to write the PIP so that the case for firing is clear if it is not met. It is possible if you make it too vague or include more things than anyone can do, that it could be contested. That is why it is important to do this in consultation with your manager and your HR to make sure that the PIP will legally serve its purpose.